# how to remove blank <p>&nbsp;</p> tags at end of paragraph

Tags: asp.net

the description which is comming from database has number of  `<p>&nbsp;</p>` these tags
so my page is occuyping large amount of blank space.
I want to remove all those blank

tag which are coming at end of page

How to do this?

Comment: Can you post some code how you output your page? Maybe   string.Replace() is a usable solution to your probelm?

Comment: If you do not require those tags then why are you storing those in your DB?

Comment: if any answer solve your problem, you should accept answer by checking right sign.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
string[] tags = {"&nbsp;","<p>","</p>","<br>"};
    string str1 = "this is best<br> &nbsp;&nbsp; tag <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p>&nbsp;in the asp.net</p>";
    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        str1 = str1.Replace(tag, "");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue with Tiny MCE in the Umbraco CMS. A work around can be found here:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/6266-Empty-p-tag-when-inserting-macro-into-text-editor - tho this is for C# but may help you in the right direction